OpenApi maven plugin isn't generating artifacts
I have strange problem. I used example from tutorial: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-libraries-2 for checking OpenApi generation.
I want to generate second artifact so all I did I extended the existing configuration and my POM part of OpenApi now looks like this:
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petstore.yml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>com.baeldung.openapi.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.baeldung.openapi.model</modelPackage>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <groupId>com.test.api.v1</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test-api-schema</artifactId>
                        <artifactVersion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</artifactVersion>
                        <includeCollapsedSpecInArtifacts>true</includeCollapsedSpecInArtifacts>

                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            ApiUtil.java
                        </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <delegatePattern>false</delegatePattern>
                            <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

As you can see the only difference are those lanes:
                    <groupId>com.test.api.v1</groupId>
                    <artifactId>test-api-schema</artifactId>
                    <artifactVersion>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</artifactVersion>

After running mvn generate-sources build pass but I dont have anywhere my artifact (I expect that in target there will be normal pom file etc which I can just run) and I have this:

Can anyone assist ? I remember on swagger plugin it was out of the box when you defined artifact properties but on openapi I cannot make it working.
